# Why is it okay to divide these random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1160249/589373) answer about the Box-Muller transform because I am stuck on the same exercise and I am essentially stuck when I compute the inverse of my transformation.

Firstly, why can we just divide $X_1$ by $X_2$? Can't $X_2$ simply be equal to $0$ and this doesn't make sense? Secondly, why can we just take the $\arctan$ to conclude that $U_1=\frac{1}{2\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{X_2}{X_1}\right)$? It is not true that $\arctan(\tan x)=x$ for any real number $x$.

I am sorry if these questions are trivial, but I am really a beginner in probability and statistics.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of that question, $P(X_1=0)=0$, so it is ok to divide by $X_1$.

We are specifically given that $0 \le U_1 \le 1$, so I think they are using $\arctan$ specifically to map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0, 2\pi]$ so that mapping from $X_2/X_1$ to $2\pi U_1$ makes sense.

Comment: thank you! How would one view $\arctan$ as a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0, 2\pi]$?

Comment: I think that you were thinking of the function $a\tan2$, right? The one defined here, for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: @JustAnAmateur In the linked answer we have $X_2/X_1 = \tan(2 \pi U_1)$. Here we are inputting numbers in $[0, 2\pi)$ into the tangent, so you can consider $\tan$ as a function $[0, 2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}$, and $\arctan$ as the inverse of this particular function.

Comment: I see now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$X_2=0$ with probability $0$ so you can almost surely divide by $X_2$. So the equality is to be understood almost surely, but as virtually all properties in probability are invariable up to zero-probability events, this is fine.

$\arctan(\tan(x))=x$ iff $x\in(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$. For example $\arctan(\tan(\pi))=0\neq\pi$.

Comment: thank you! I agree with your second point about $\arctan(\tan(x))$, this is precisely what concerns me. However, how come their equality is still correct? Is it because it also holds almost surely? Even though that doesn't look right on second thought.

Comment: The equality is almost surely correct. When you say that $X=Y$ almost surely, you mean that the set of $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ is of probability 1. If two random variables are almost surely equal then they have the same distribution. This is why in this case we don't care that the equality holds only almost surely (like in many many other cases in probability).

Comment: thank you, but I am still a bit unsure why it holds almost surely. I mean, if $U_1\in [1/4, 1]$, then the equality doesn't hold and this is not a negligible set. Am I wrong? Or are we somehow using a modification of the usual $\arctan$ as angryavian suggested above?

Comment: $X_1=0$ iff $\cos(2\pi U_1)=0$, that is iff $U_1=1/4$ or $U_1=3/4$. This happens with probability 0. I don't understand where your $[1/4,1]$ comes from.

Comment: Sorry, I am tired and I wasn't precise. I was referring to the equality $U_1=\frac{1}{2\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{X_2}{X_1}\right)$.