# Box-Muller transform monotonicity?

Tags: transformation, jacobian

I have been following the proof of the Box-Muller transform, (eg [Box-Muller Transform Normality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005236/box-muller-transform-normality)) and I have a question about the process of finding the pdf of the transformed variables. Doesn’t the transformation have to be monotonic in order to use this formula:

$$f_{U, T}(u,t) = f_{X,Y}(x, y) |\delta(x,y) / \delta(u, t) |$$

Comment: The actual important property is that the transformation is one-to-one. In 1D a continuous function is one-to-one if and only if it is strictly monotone.

Comment: Isn’t the Box-Muller transformation many-to-one? (Due to the sin and cos)

Comment: If you ignore the origin in the original space (which you can, without hurting this calculation), it is one-to-one. That is to say, each point besides the origin in the original space matches up with exactly one point in the polar coordinate space.